# How to use .onclick event for multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, I have a rectangle on my html page, and want to rotate it for 90deg by clicking on it:

```
rectangle.onclick = () => {

   rectangle.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
```

When I click once - it rotates,but when i wanna rotate it for the second time - it does not work. Is there any way to to use .onclick event for two or more times?

Comment: It likely is working, the issue is you're not increasing the rotation angle beyond 90 degrees in subsequent clicks.

Comment: It is used multiple times, your rectangle rotate just once, because if you click again, the style remains rotate(90deg)

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). You don't want to add `onclick` multiple times; you want to keep track of how much your element has been rotated. Note that there is a way of adding multiple handlers to a single event; [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). It's the preferred method for adding event handlers.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Pace your comment, he did *not* ask how to add the listener multiple times. He asked how to get it to fire more than once. This, because he mistakenly thought it was not firing, on account of a learner's misunderstanding of CSS. Sometimes, people don't understand clearly enough to ask the right question. And that really *is* okay.

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan Pace you comment. Where did I say it wasn't okay? I merely stated it was an XY Problem. Which it is. I know he didn't ask how to add an event handler multiple times, that's why it's a note on a comment on a question, not an answer. The point being (and this could be extended to your answer) that `onclick` is deprecated in favor of `addEventListener`. Beginner or no, using the right tool for the job is important.

Answer (score 3):

CSS is not stateful; that is, when you set "rotate(90)" it doesn't rotate the item 90 degrees *further*, it rotates it to exactly 90 degrees from 0. So, if you want to rotate it, you need to set the correct angle: 90, 180, 270, &c. You can use a simple state variable to keep track of your angle, like this:

```js
let rotation = 0 // rotation angle variable

rectangle.onclick = () => {
  if (rotation >= 360) {
    rotation = 0
  } else {
    rotation += 90;
  }
  rectangle.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation}deg)`;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set pentangle.style.transform, you're setting a style. That transform is from the baseline, unrotated shape. Your onclick event is likely getting fired multiple times, but each time, it does the same thing: cause the pentangle to be rotated from its default orientation.

You'll need something more like this, which advances the rotation amount based on the current rotation.

```
pentangle.onclick = () => {

   if(pentangle.style.transform == "rotate(90deg)")
       pentangle.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
   else if(pentangle.style.transform == "rotate(180deg)")
       pentangle.style.transform = "rotate(270deg)";
   else if(pentangle.style.transform == "rotate(270deg)")
       pentangle.style.transform = "";
   else
       pentangle.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
```